# File corrupted when passed as URLEncodedBytes via HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-web-api2, httpwebrequest

I have a .Net service that packages up changes from one system and sends them to an old web service that accepts and process the changes into another system.

The .Net service uses this code to send the request:

```
    private HttpWebRequest BuildPostRequest()
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("USERID=username&PASSWORD=pwd&SYSTEM=system&PERDATA=");
        byte[] filebytes = File.ReadAllBytes(WORKPATH + "uploadPackage.zip");
        byte[] encodedFileBytes = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncodeToBytes(filebytes);

        var section = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("securitySettings") as NameValueCollection;
        string username = section["Username"].ToString();
        string password = section["Password"].ToString();
        string authString = username + ":" + password;
        authString = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authString));

        HttpWebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create(TARGETURL) as HttpWebRequest;
        req.KeepAlive = true;
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authString;
        req.PreAuthenticate = true;
        req.Timeout = 350000;
        req.ReadWriteTimeout = 350000;

        using (Stream rqStream = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            rqStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            rqStream.Write(encodedFileBytes, 0, encodedFileBytes.Length); 
        }

        return req;
    }
```

This part works with the old web service.  The old web service is able to grab the PERDATA form data and restore it to a zip file on the file system, unzip the file and work with the files from the zip file in order to update the local data.

We're now trying to replace the old web service with a new web service written in .Net.  I have the following code trying to do what the old web service did -- get the form data, write the data as a file and unzip the file; however, the zip file that gets written is not correct  and my code bombs when trying to unzip.

Here is what I was attempting:

```
public class InputModel
 {
    public string userid { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string system { get; set; }
    public string perdata { get; set; }
}

    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Changes([FromBody] InputModel model)
    {
            //Write PerData to File and Unzip
            var fileoutName = path + @"\perdata.zip";
            var data = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecodeToBytes(model.perdata);
            File.WriteAllBytes(fileoutName, data);

            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(fileoutName, path);

            ...
        });
    }
```

I realize that this would be much better handled by sending a multi-part form request; but I'm constrained to ensure that the system continues to work with the old service at this point -- and it isn't able to work with a multi-part request.

However, it would appear that I'm doing everything that would be needed to pass the file as a "string" -- but as I said, it just isn't working.

You can see that the original file and the received file (written to disk) are not the same:
[image: Image of Original zip file prior to being sent]

[image: Image of file after uploaded and saved]

Comment: are you allowed to pass that file as a base64 string?

Comment: also: why don't you upload the images to SE's imgur instead if your onedrive?

Comment: @rene I haven't tried that primarily because the old web service is working as is.  If I encode with base64, it could potentially break the old web service.  In regard to imgur, I tried, but it kept rejecting my images as unsupported (even though they're .png and .jpg)

Comment: Can you try to make perdata a `byte[]` instead of string?

Comment: I tried that and that does not work.  Nothing gets mapped into perdata if it is of type `byte[]`